# Typecasting String to Parser object while using Argparse - python

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to retrieve all the argument information using arg1.dest, arg1.help etc.. for all the different arguments from arg1 to arg3. I am using a for loop by adding arg + "1,2,3" so that I can retrieve it within one loop and not use different insert commands while i write the sql code for insertion later. I am facing a typecasting error here. arg1 is a parser object previously but since i am converting to string and appending it, I am not able to access arg1.dest or arg1.help any longer.

Do we have a way to type case it to proper parser object? Any inputs are highly appreciated.

```
import argparse

def fibo(num):
    a,b = 0,1
    for i in range(num):
        a,b=b,a+b
    return a

def Main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="To the find the fibonacci number of the give number")
    arg1 = parser.add_argument("num",help="The fibnocacci number to calculate:", type=int)
    arg2 = parser.add_argument("-p", "--password", dest="password", help="current appliance password")
    arg3 =parser.add_argument("-i", "--ignore", action="store_true", dest="ignore")
    parser.add_argument("-x", "--dbinsert", help="insert data in db",action="store_true")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    result = fibo(args.num)
    print("The "+str(args.num)+"th fibonacci number is "+str(result))

    if args.dbinsert:
        for x in range(1,len(vars(args))):
            value = ("arg"+str(x))
            print(value.dest)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        Main()
-----------------------------------------------------------------
When I run : python myping.py 10 --dbinsert
Output : The 10th fibonacci number is 55
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "myping.py", line 42, in <module>
   Main()
 File "myping.py", line 34, in Main
  print(value.dest)
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dest'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `value = ("arg"+str(x))` to `value = locals()["arg"+str(x)]`.